# How does the Vector Math Normalize node work?

Tags: node-editor

As I understand, the normalize setting should convert a vector into a unit vector. However, I am confused as two what the second vector input does in this operation. Normalizing should only require one vector input right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `normalize option` the node will only normalize **the first input** vector (set the length to 1). You are right, a **second vector isn't needed** for this operation.

*This example shows how it can be used to multiply a vector by a scalar:*

[image]

Comment: I recently encountered another instance of this with Cycles nodes where only one of the inputs is actually used.  I think this was done to avoid the extra code needed for lots of different node configurations.  It is confusing.