# I want to mix Cycles shaders based on self shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, drivers

I have a sphere (world) that I want to reveal the night lights on. I can use a normal node and manually rotate the DOT product, then I use this as a factor mix between Day time shader and Night time shader.

But I want an interactive version so I only have to move the light in 3D view.

I guessed that maybe I could take the Lamp's position as a driver value and modify the position normal of my sphere. See screeny:

[image]

But I can't figure the math to take all angles into account.

Comment: I have a similar setup in my [.blend here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45679/599), but based on the rotation of a sun lamp rather than position.. At the very least you could use a track to constraint or something to convert the position to a rotation, in case it's not possible to do the necessary maths in the driver itself

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip, I just tried a rotating sun lamp but couldn't express  an opposite value for some reason (being innumerate I guess)

Comment: This question has two good answers. One of them should be marked as correct.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can choose one, as they both approach the problem from different directions. One is driver based, the other node based. Both are important to understand. I would choose the smaller one but the driver answer is probably more important to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A further answer was provided by Viktor Mukayev https://twitter.com/vitos1k who suggested using the texture co-ordinates node to produce a Dot Product:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Turns out this is pretty easy to do. "Easy" as in "you're deprived of doing all the fun math manually" ;)

1. Add three *Value* nodes (or a single *Combine XYZ* node) into which drivers can be added. I prefer the three value node approach in case you want to access individual axes later on.
2. Add *[drivers](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html)* to each of the value nodes by right clicking on each and selecting *Add Driver*.
3. In the *Graph Editor* and switch to *Drivers* mode in the header (1).

   [image]

   Ensure that both the object using the material and the value nodes are selected, then repeat the following until all the drivers are set up:

   2. Select the next driver in the driver list on the left of the graph editor
   3. Select the driver target, in this case the point lamp (you can press <kbd>E</kbd> while hovering over this field, then click on the lamp in the 3D view for a speedier selection workflow)
   4. Set the transform type to *X*, *Y*, or *Z Location*, making sure to pick the right one for each driver
   5. Set the driver type to *Sum Values*. We don't need any fancy scripted python stuff, and avoiding the *Scripted Expression* setting will prevent the drivers from being disabled for security reasons.
4. If you put the drivers on value nodes, connect them to a Combine XYZ node.
5. Add a *Vector Math* node set to *Normalize* and connect the Combine XYZ node. This will ensure the values from the driver are scaled down to the 0..1 range.
   Note that only the [first input of the normalize node is used](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18870/599), so I've hidden the extraneous sockets with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.
6. Take the *Dot Product* of the normalized location and the object's normals (obtained from either a *Texture Coordinate* or *Geometry* node) via another *Vector Math* node.
7. Adjust the scalar result of the dot product to suit our needs better with some math nodes and a colorramp:

   [image]

The resulting gradient should update in real time:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, seems like the sort of thing an addon would be good at setting up. Really glad that I asked now.

Comment: Turns out that in Blender 2.8 Eevee, currently Texture (alt) Object Position is not available so this is the working solution for Eevee ;-)