# How do I change between different images based on the rotation of the camera

Tags: camera, tracking

[image: Example]

This is the 3D setup in blender with the plane always facing the camera. The method I used here was animating the texuture. I want to know If there is a method for the image to automatically change based on the camera's rotation.

Comment: How are you rendering this, which Engine? Cycles, Blender Internal, Game Engine? All solutions would have to be render engine specific

Comment: I guess in this case the *drivers* may be helpful. I am not an expert in this field though :(.

Comment: Sorry Guys I forgot to mention this is rendered with cycles.

Comment: Changing the source of texture would be hard, but I have this angular solution from a lighting query... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47175/i-want-to-mix-cycles-shaders-based-on-self-shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a node setup that gives you the object / world space normals of the face, then get you the horizontal direction of the face using atan2(x,y) and use that as a mix factor between various images.

For us to determine which texture we want to use, we need to know the direction in which a face is pointing. It just so happens that in computer graphics there is the concept of a **normal vector**, which is just what we need: a set of numbers that describe the direction in which a face is pointing.

To get said normal vector we use the *Normal* output of the *Geometry* node. There is a problem though, the normal output of the geometry node in the BGE gives you screen space normals. This means that the direction of the face is defined **relative to the camera**, and **not relative to the world**, which is what we actually need. Nowadays it is very simple to convert between spaces, we use the vector transform node.

Now we have a vector that tells us the direction of the face, but what even is a vector? Well, a vector is a set of three numbers, with each one representing a distance moved along each Cartesian axis. But that is not very intuitive when it comes to figure out the actual angle that a face is pointing in.

Luckily there is an function that takes two components of a vector and tells you that angle that they are rotated around the third axis; this function is called `atan2()` in computer science and `arctangent-with-two-arguments` in maths.

ATan2 is a somewhat complex function so I will not go in depth with it, here is the wikipedia page about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

The cool thing about atan2 is that you can plug the `x` and `y` components of your `world space normal vector` into it and get the angle around the `z` axis in which that face is pointing. By the way, you will have to **recreate and normalize** (in this case, normalize means mapping the standard range of values that atan2 gives you, which is from `-pi to pi` to the range from `-1` to `1`) atan2 using nodes because it is not a function that Blender has by default; or just take the one I made from the .blend that included in this post.

After that all that is needed is some more simple math to show the right texture when it's needed. In my example file I use a spritesheet with various textures and shift the texture along when it's needed. You can also use multiple images, but keep in mind the (small yet significant) increase in memory usage and texture fetches when using multiple textures.

I actually have an example .blend of exactly that laying around, I started experimenting with it when I saw an Uncharted 4 tech demo video a while back.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1cD1S7QjpHCMUdCaGUxczBPaFE

If you want to see it working in the example file just hit <kbd>P</kbd> on your keyboard while hovering over the *3D View*.

Some mild modifications should make this work in Cycles or BI, it is currently set up to work with the Blender Game Engine.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please expand a bit on how to achieve the desired result. Link only answers are discouraged here. While example files are encouraged if you link goes down or you remove the file your answer becomes empty and irrelevant for any future visitors. Some screenshots or a textual explanation will do

Comment: OK, I'll try to expand my reply

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos edited, I think it is satisfactory now

Comment: @Sebastián Mestre . I wish I was smart like you. Everything works perfect the only thing I had to change in cycles was the division amount. It had to correlate to the number of images in the UV. Thanks Sebastián!! [example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r7p5.gif) and [node setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyXlM.jpg)

Comment: @SebastiánMestre Do you think this method could work for the X and Y rotations of the camera?

Comment: @MitchellGreenland No problem, mate! And Yes! Just plug red(x) and blue(z) into atan 2 for the angle around the y axis or green(y) and blue(z) for the angle around the x axis. should work exactly the same

Comment: @SebastiánMestre I can't seem to make them work at the same time. Is there a way you know of to display only the X rotation (YZ node) images when it reaches. I want to get like a top down view as well.

Comment: @MitchellGreenland Well, you should have a set of textures for the top down, as well as for the side view. and chose wich one you want to use depending on the normal Z (screen space if you're using a billboard and world space if you're having the face always point at the camera). But really this should be on a different question

Comment: @SebastiánMestre It's still the same question as it is relating to rotation of the camera

Comment: @MitchellGreenland I disagree. I did answer your question though, best of luck!

Comment: @SebastiánMestre I don't want to ask a whole other question..you seem to have a good grasp of this concept i was hoping you could help. I can rotate the camera in the Z rotation and the images change accordingly. I can rotate the camera around the X axis and the change accordingly. I want to know if I can disable the view of the Z rotation images and show the X rotation images when the x rotation reaches a 45 degree angle

Comment: @MitchellGreenland As i mentioned previously, I would use the normal's Z component to do this. But the right answer would imply converting the view vector to tangent space, wich involves a pretty long node setup and some matrix maths.

I will tell you the simple way using the normal Z and if you want the actual answer then you'll have to ask a new question-

Take the normal output of a geometry node and turn it into camera space(use the vector transform node). Separate its values and put the B value throug a math (greater than) node, set the other field to 0.5 and use that as a mix factor.