# Node editor help: Using textures as shadows

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, npr

I like NPR renders that use painted on textures like in [this project](https://sketchfab.com/models/0ea14eb68edb446b982de37e0571a97d) by Gregory Khodyrev (preview below)

[image]

The only issue is that the shadows are normally painted on as well so they aren't very animation friendly. I was thinking what if you could have two layers one lit layer and one shadow layer. Place the shadow layer onto the material and use some type of variable like a normal vector or a sky texture as a movable mask using the lit layer which can simulate sunlight hitting it. Or alternatively use a shadeless material, set up a variable that detects weather or not a normal is being hit by a ray of light, and if it is it will project the lit texture onto that normal.

However, I don't know enough about about the node editor to know if either of these methods is even possible.

Comment: Is it not possible to just import the model with the textures, add a lamp and render?

Comment: What you describe is pretty much how you do this. Look at peoples versions of dot screen or cross hatching materials.

Comment: Also see this response for altering a shadow based on another object's angle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47175/i-want-to-mix-cycles-shaders-based-on-self-shadow